# Use Component class variable inside Component host

Tags: angular, typescript

Do you know how can I make use of a `class` variable inside the `@Component` declaration?

This is the desired approach:

```js
@Component({
    selector: "whatever",
    host: {
        "[class]":"className"
    }
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() className:string="my-class-name";
}
```

Expected results:

```
<whatever class="my-class-name"></whatever>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the [HostBinding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostBinding-interface.html) decorator to set the desired CSS class back to the host element:

```
@HostBinding('class.my-class-name')
protected get myClass() { 
    return true; 
}
```

[Edit]

The above example shows how to set a static CSS class to the host element. To set a dynamic class, then you will need to decorate the className property with `HostBinding` decorator:

```
@HostBinding('class')
@Input()
public className:string = "my-class-name";
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/iPbrYbUSZtkHiGLDyo2B?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I already tried that, but I need to set the `css class` value to whatever value the `className` input has, not hardcoding it.
The thing is that I don't know which class or value the `className` input it's going to  have, so "hardcoding" it with:
     `@HostBinding('class.my-class-name')` 
is not an option. :/

Comment: I updated the answer to demonstrate how to set the class dynamically. Sorry for missing the initial question :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the correct answer!  :D